# When my app returns from a backgroud process, it loses the last settings

Tags: android

I try to use ViewModel, see below:

```
public class ViewDispoViewModel extends ViewModel {

    @Nullable
    private boolean swDispo = true;
    private String mDateSelVM;

    public String getDateSel() {
        return mDateSelVM;
    }

    public void setDateSel(String mDateSelVM) {
        this.mDateSelVM = mDateSelVM;
    }

}
```

in MainActicvity, I read getDateSel:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.viewdispoactivity);

        mDateSel = viewdispoViewModel.getDateSel();
        if (mDateSel == null) {
            dateda = new Date();
            datea = new Date();
        } else {
            try {
                dateda = dateFormat.parse(mDateSel);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime ( dateda );
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                dateda = cal.getTime();
                datea = dateda;
                //datea = dateFormat.parse(mDateSel);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

when I change the data, I set new data in viewmodel
but when i minimize the app and open it again, mDateSel  is null.

```
viewdispoViewModel.setDateSel(dateFormat.format(dateda));
```

Tanks for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shared Preferences for this

set values example

```
SharedPreferences pref =   
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putBoolean("swDispo", true);
edit.putString("mDateSelVM", "your_string");
edit.commit();
```

get values example

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String username = pref.getString("mDateSelVM", "default value"); 
Boolean yourLocked = prefs.getBoolean("swDispo", false);
```

how to exactly activities work can be found here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

onPause in Activity - save your values in SharedPreferences or in Application (not Activity).

onResume in Activity - update select items of your spinners from this values.
read about various states of an activity

[various states of an actiivty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqtl0.png)